# How to get the length of a string in c, if it has integers in it

Tags: c, string, sizeof

I am familiar with the `sizeof` operation in C, but when I use it for the string `"1234abcd"` it only returns `4`, which I am assuming is accounting for the last 4 characters.
So how would I get this to be a string of size 8?

specific code is as follows:

```
FILE *in_file;
in_file = fopen(filename, "r");     
if (in_file == NULL) {
    printf("File does not exist\n");
    return 1;
}

int val_to_inspect = 0;

fscanf(in_file, "%x", &val_to_inspect);

while (val_to_inspect != 0) {
    printf("%x", val_to_inspect);
    int length = sizeof val_to_inspect;
    printf("%d", length);
```

Again, the string that is being read from the file is `"1234abcd"`, just to clarify.

Comment: `sizeof` will give you the size of a data type. Check out `strlen()`.

Comment: `int len1 = 0, len2 = 0; fscanf(in_file," %n%x%n", &len1, &val_to_inspect, &len2); int length = len2 - len1;`

Answer (score 4):

There're a couple of issues here:

`sizeof` operator returns the size of the object. In this case it returns the size of `val_to_inspect`, which is an `int`.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

`fscanf` reads from a stream and interprets it. You are only scanning an integer ("%x"), not a string.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Lastly, if you actually had a nil-terminated string, to get its length you could use `strlen()`.

Comment: More accurately, to get the length of a null-terminated string, not only *could* one use `strlen()`, one ***should*** do so.  The `sizeof` operator applied to a `char *` or `char` array computes something different (and differing between those two cases).

Comment: Never claimed sizeof is in any possibility the tool for the job :)

Comment: No, I mention `sizeof` because the OP is using it.  My comment is about your choice of wording; I have clarified that.

Comment: You could use strlen, you could feed your c-string into an std::string. You can do quite a few things, depends where it came from and what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**, to get the *length* of a string, you need to use [`strlen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).

That said, be a little cautious while using `sizeof`, it operates on the data type. So, if you pass a pointer to it, it will return you the size of the pointer variable, not the length of the *string* it points to.

Answer (score 1):

In several important ways, only some of which have anything to do with `sizeof`, you are mistaken about what your code actually does.

```
FILE *in_file;
in_file = fopen(filename, "r");     
if (in_file == NULL)
  {
    printf("File does not exist\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

Kudos for actually checking whether `fopen` succeeded; lots of people forget to do that when they are starting out in C.  However, there are many reasons why `fopen` might fail; the file not existing is just one of them.  Whenever an I/O operation fails, make sure to print `strerror(errno)` so you know the actual reason.  Also, error messages should be sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`, and should include the name of the affected file(s) if any.  Corrected code looks like

```
if (in_file == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
```

(You will need to add includes of `string.h` and `errno.h` to the top of the file if they aren't already there.)

```
int val_to_inspect = 0;
fscanf(in_file,"%x", &val_to_inspect);
```

This code does *not* read a string from the file.  It skips any leading whitespace and then reads a sequence of hexadecimal digits from the file, stopping as soon as it encounters a non-digit, and immediately converts them to a machine number which is stored in `val_to_expect`.  With the file containing `1234abcd`, it will indeed read eight characters from the file, but with other file contents it might read more or fewer.

(Technically, with the `%x` conversion specifier you should be using an *unsigned* int, but most implementations will let you get away with using a signed int.)

(When you get more practice in C you will learn that `scanf` is broken-as-specified and also very difficult to use robustly, but for right now don't worry about that.)

```
while (val_to_inspect != 0) {
    printf("%x", val_to_inspect);
    int length = sizeof val_to_inspect;
    printf("%d", length);
}
```

You are not applying `sizeof` to a string, you are applying it to an `int`.  The size of an `int`, on your computer, is 4 `char`s, and that is true *no matter what the value is*.

Moreover, `sizeof` applied to an actual C string (that is, a `char *` variable pointing to a NUL-terminated sequence of characters) does *not* compute the length of the string.  It will instead tell you the size of the *pointer* to the string, which will be a constant (usually either 4 or 8, depending on the computer) independent of the length of the string. To compute the length of a string, use the library function `strlen` (declared in `string.h`).

You will sometimes see clever code apply `sizeof` to a *string literal*, which does return a number related to (but not equal to!) its length.  Exercise for you: figure out what that number is, and why `sizeof` does this for string literals but not for strings in general.  (Hint: `sizeof s` will return a number related to `s`'s string length when `s` was declared as `char s[] = "string";`, but *not* when it was declared as `char *s = "string";`.)

As a final note, it doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things whether you like your opening braces on their own lines or not, but *pick one style and stick to it throughout the entire file*.  Don't put some `if` opening braces on their own lines and others at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: I would say: *The size of an `int`, on your computer, is 4 **bytes**...*

Comment: @chqrlie A _byte_ is not necessarily the same size as a _`char`_.  `sizeof` is defined in terms of `char` units.  (Yes, this is horribly pedantic, but I have been yelled at before on this very website for glossing over the distinction, so.)

Comment: I'm afraid you are incorrect. the `char` type in C and C++ is by definition the smallest addressable unit and has a size of 1. It is exactly one byte. Conversely, the byte does not necessarily have 8 bits, older systems used to have 9-bit bytes, and some DSP processors have 16-bit or even 32-bit bytes. The reason I insist on the word *byte* is because the `char` type has specific semantics attached, such as potential signedness, which are irrelevant when laking about the size of an object. OTOH the `char` type in Java is 16 bits, which requires 2 bytes on most systems.

Comment: The C Standard defines the value of `sizeof` this way: ***6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators** [...] The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand...*

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create own counter to find the length of `"1234abcd"` by reading the character by character.

```
FILE *in_file;
char ch;
int length=0;

in_file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
if (in_file == NULL)
{
    printf("File does not exist\n");
    return 1;
}
while (1) {
    ch = fgetc(in_file);
    printf("%c", ch);
    if (ch == EOF)
        break;
    length++;
}
fclose(in_file);
printf ("\n%d",length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, thank you for all the feedback. I realize I made a lot of mistakes with the original post, but im just switching to c from c++, so a lot of the things I'm used to cant really be applied the same way. This is all tremendously helpful, it's good to have a place to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Len=sizeof(your string)/sizeof(char)-1
-1 is eof character null
If you want to get length of any from specific begining index just do Len-index